# В Idea запускается, а через терминал выдает ошибку: Error creating bean

Tags: java, консоль, intellij-idea, spring-security

При запуске через idea все компилируется и выдает вот такой результат:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.2.2.RELEASE)

2023-07-18 16:09:47.897  INFO 4120 --- [           main] c.g.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin      : Starting SocialLogin on MacBook-Pro-Egor.local with PID 4120 (started by egorshapovalov in /Users/egorshapovalov/IdeaProjects/social-login copy)
2023-07-18 16:09:47.898  INFO 4120 --- [           main] c.g.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin      : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2023-07-18 16:09:48.244  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2023-07-18 16:09:48.248  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2023-07-18 16:09:48.248  INFO 4120 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.29]
2023-07-18 16:09:48.282  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2023-07-18 16:09:48.282  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 364 ms
2023-07-18 16:09:48.365  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2023-07-18 16:09:48.386  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page: class path resource [static/index.html]
2023-07-18 16:09:48.571  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Creating filter chain: any request, [org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@e95595b, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter@4cb702ce, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@21263314, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@6fff46bf, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@17b37e9a, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2AuthorizationRequestRedirectFilter@687e6293, org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.OAuth2LoginAuthenticationFilter@1faf386c, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@64c781a9, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@40247d48, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@5a917723, org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter@4a92c6a9, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@642857e0, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@2ead6ba4]
2023-07-18 16:09:48.592  INFO 4120 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2023-07-18 16:09:48.593  INFO 4120 --- [           main] c.g.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin      : Started SocialLogin in 0.828 seconds (JVM running for 1.059)
```

а вот когда я создаю jar файл и пытаюсь запустить его через терминал мне выдет седующий результат

```
16:00:31.758 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.context.support.StandardServletEnvironment - Activating profiles []

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::                        

16:00:31.824 [main] INFO com.gitHibAutharization.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin - Starting SocialLogin on MacBook-Pro-Egor.local with PID 3988 (/Users/egorshapovalov/IdeaProjects/social-login/build/libs/social-login-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by egorshapovalov in /Users/egorshapovalov/IdeaProjects/social-login/build/libs)
16:00:31.824 [main] DEBUG com.gitHibAutharization.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin - Running with Spring Boot, Spring
16:00:31.825 [main] INFO com.gitHibAutharization.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin - No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
16:00:31.825 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Loading source class com.gitHibAutharization.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin
16:00:31.852 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6591f517
16:00:31.857 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor'
16:00:31.862 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory'
16:00:32.077 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer'
16:00:32.079 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator'
16:00:32.812 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'mvcUriComponentsContributor' via factory method to bean named 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'
16:00:32.813 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'httpRequestHandlerAdapter'
16:00:32.813 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'simpleControllerHandlerAdapter'
16:00:32.813 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'handlerExceptionResolver'
16:00:32.813 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'handlerExceptionResolver' via factory method to bean named 'mvcContentNegotiationManager'
16:00:32.815 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver - ControllerAdvice beans: 0 @ExceptionHandler, 1 ResponseBodyAdvice
16:00:32.815 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'mvcViewResolver'
16:00:32.816 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'mvcViewResolver' via factory method to bean named 'mvcContentNegotiationManager'
16:00:32.816 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'defaultViewResolver'
16:00:32.817 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'viewResolver'
16:00:32.818 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'viewResolver' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@757acd7b'
16:00:32.818 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration$ClassProxyingConfiguration'
16:00:32.818 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration$ClassProxyingConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@757acd7b'
16:00:32.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.aop.AopAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.context.ConfigurationPropertiesAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.http.JacksonHttpMessageConvertersConfiguration'
16:00:32.820 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.821 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
16:00:32.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoAutoConfiguration' via constructor to bean named 'spring.info-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.info.ProjectInfoProperties'
16:00:32.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.client.servlet.OAuth2ClientAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.servlet.OAuth2ResourceServerAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.822 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'spring.security.oauth2.resourceserver-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.OAuth2ResourceServerProperties'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'authenticationManagerBuilder'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'authenticationManagerBuilder' via factory method to bean named 'objectPostProcessor'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'authenticationManagerBuilder' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6591f517'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'authenticationEventPublisher'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SecurityAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.823 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'authenticationEventPublisher' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6591f517'
16:00:32.825 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration'
16:00:32.833 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents'
16:00:32.833 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'autowiredWebSecurityConfigurersIgnoreParents' via factory method to bean named 'org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@757acd7b'
16:00:32.838 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'delegatingApplicationListener'
16:00:32.839 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'springSecurityFilterChain'
16:00:32.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration'
16:00:32.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.configuration.AuthenticationConfiguration$EnableGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer - Eagerly initializing {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration@36c2d629}
16:00:32.840 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager'
16:00:32.841 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Creating shared instance of singleton bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration'
16:00:32.841 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory - Autowiring by type from bean name 'inMemoryUserDetailsManager' via factory method to bean named 'spring.security-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.SecurityProperties'
16:00:32.842 [main] INFO org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration - 

Using generated security password: 3e72f53f-702e-46fb-ae13-e1d13845d898

16:00:32.865 [main] WARN org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' available
16:00:32.865 [main] INFO org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor - Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
Jul 18, 2023 4:00:32 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
16:00:32.874 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configuration/WebSecurityConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:656)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:484)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.gitHibAutharization.GitHibAutharization.SocialLogin.main(SocialLogin.java:59)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]: Factory method 'springSecurityFilterChain' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:651)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository' available
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:351)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:342)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1126)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientConfigurerUtils.getClientRegistrationRepositoryBean(OAuth2ClientConfigurerUtils.java:53)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2ClientConfigurerUtils.getClientRegistrationRepository(OAuth2ClientConfigurerUtils.java:46)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer.init(OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java:479)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configurers.oauth2.client.OAuth2LoginConfigurer.init(OAuth2LoginConfigurer.java:135)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.init(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:370)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:324)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:292)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity.performBuild(WebSecurity.java:79)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.doBuild(AbstractConfiguredSecurityBuilder.java:333)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.AbstractSecurityBuilder.build(AbstractSecurityBuilder.java:41)
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfiguration.springSecurityFilterChain(WebSecurityConfiguration.java:104)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
    ... 22 common frames omitted
```

Jar файл я создаю нажав build в меню gradle

[image: menu gradle in IntelliJ IDEA]

Answer (score 0):

прописал в build.gradle.kts, plugins

```
 id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "2.5.7"
```